# How do I find out more about an installed iOS app that's been de-listed from the store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I just discovered a pretty shady-looking app on my kids' iPad (just says "Free Video" under the icon?).  I don't *think* they should be able to install apps, given the way I have permissions set up, but I could be wrong if the app is free.  I'll worry about that later.  I just want to know more about it.

My first thought was to look at the App Store entry for the app -- it's not a jailbroken device, so it must have been installed through the Store, right? -- but I can't find it by searching my Purchases section, nor by searching "Free Video" in the main store.  I thought perhaps it had been on the store, then got de-listed.

It's still installed.  Is there any way to bring up the Store page for an arbitrary installed app?  Alternately, is there a standard way to find out more about an installed app e.g. through settings -- when it was installed and how, who published it, etc?

Comment: Can you connect the iOS device to iTunes and transfer purchases? That way you'll have the IPA file on a Mac or a PC and can look into the developer account that signed the app. Basically, you don't get easy tools on iOS to pick apart app signing.

Comment: It would be cool if you could post a screenshot of it, but it sounds like the 'app' might not be an app, but rather a home screen icon of a web page. Have you tried opening it? If it opens safari, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: @Vitalydotn, I did run it and it's a full-fledged app.  I'm hesitant to poke around; I was hoping to find out more from the store / OS before I spent any time with it.  I guess not?